# Beautiful Soup Returning HTML full of Variables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have created a list of links that connect to pages from LinkedIn. These links were aggregated using LinkedIns recruiter function (behind a paywall). When I paste the links into my browser and inspect the html code, it looks standard and I am able to easily ID the element I am searching for (see below).

However, when I run my python code and use beautiful soup to get the HTML, the HTML that comes back looks nothing like how it looks on the browser's inspect element view. Instead of normal tags the HTML is filled with variables and basically looks like nothing I have seen before (have not done a ton of scraping).

Is it possible to get HTML that looks like what I am seeing on my browser as opposed to this crazy looking stuff? The links were complied using the recuriter search function so I think I am somehow pulling html with search variables as opposed to actual results, but I really have no idea.

One of the webpage links: https://www.linkedin.com/recruiter/profile/168561385,W0U7,CAP?searchController=smartSearch&searchId=3392867616&pos=424&total=973&searchCacheKey=f4b1a865-50e8-4f59-ba48-9dff595e63e5%2CoUbi&searchRequestId=8322c8e0-4b99-4d99-b860-1bdef1653e8c%2CXsP1&searchSessionId=3392867616&origin=PAGE&memberAuth=168561385%2CW0U7%2CCAP

This is the code I used to create the file with html. I want the last line to extract the data I am looking for assuming I can get the correct html.

```
#Used to create file
with open('departures.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        browser.get(row['link'])
        page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
        html = page.prettify()
        with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
            file.write(unicode(html))

    #Code I want to Run right now it just returns an empty list
    position = page.find_all('span', class_= 'keyword')
```

HTML I am trying to find that shows up when I use browser to go to link:

```
<span class="keyword"> Account Manager</span>

Small Piece of Actual HTML returned: <code id="profile-data" style="display: none;">
<!--{"breadcrumbs":{"customSearchURL":"/recruiter/smartsearch? updateSearchHistory=false&decorateHits=true&decorateFacets=false&doFacetCounting=true&searchHistoryId=3392867616&resetFacets=false&searchCacheKey=f4b1a865-50e8-4f59-ba48-9dff595e63e5%2CoUbi&searchRequestId=4d25da0f-1f73-4722-8586-9652b3f98b97%2CQSZO&doResultCaching=false&forceResultFromCache=false&origin=PPSL&doProjectBasedCounting=false&count=25&start=700","linkContext":"Controller:smartSearch,Action:search,ID:3392867616","context":
```

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn uses a lot of JavaScript to generate the page you see in the browser. The DOM element inspector in the developer tools shows you the current result of that JS execution, not the original HTML page that the browser downloaded.

To view the actual HTML page source in the browser, use View Source (Ctrl+U or Command+U). That should show HTML similar to what you get in Python.

If you need to do some scraping that works on the final generated DOM output, you may want to use a [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) that can execute JavaScript such as [Chrome controlled by Puppeteer](https://blog.bitsrc.io/web-scraping-with-puppeteer-e73e5fee7474).

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this with python/selenium? I am not very familiar with javascript.